# Setting a limit to movie ratings in matrix factorization

Tags: machine-learning, matrix-factorization, recommendation-engine

Is there a way to limit the movie rating output from matrix factorization algorithm? I had a matrix with ratings ranging from 1 to 5 but after training the model, some movies are rated above 5. Is it normal? Is there a way to normalize the ratings in order to have ratings strictly between 1-5.

In the link below https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282663370_Film_Recommendation_Systems_using_Matrix_Factorization_and_Collaborative_Filtering, they mentioned about normalization before running the algorithm, I couldn't try it yet but still, I don't have the feeling it will solve the problem.

Comment: Just clip it after. Yes... it's normal (to some extent).

Comment: Hi Sascha, What do you mean by clip it after? Could you develop a little bit more, please?

Comment: Just use the nearest value from your allowed range. Like [numpy's clip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)